# How to improve battery performance and consumption issue in android application development?

Tags: android, performance, optimization

How to improve battery performance and consumption issue in android application development.

Please provide best practice to avoid battery consumption issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VC2Hlb22mZM

Comment: Do you want to improve battery performance of the android device or the device which you're using for development? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

There is pretty good documentation about optimizing battery life on android developer site.

https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/index.html

In general if you do networking in your application use JobScheduler, SyncAdapter etc this API-s help you networking efficient without worrying about battery.

Also you can get charging states through Intent filter and get battery level so you can do change frequency of task depends on battery state